# pass arraylist<CustomObject> from Activity to varioud fragments using parcablearraylist

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist

I want to pass Arraylist of Customized Ojects from my activity to my fragments and i am trying to pass it through Parcelable Arraylist but i am not able to do it can anyone help ? anymethod to pass arraylist is acceptable from activity to fragments

My code

```
 String driverId = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_data").getJSONObject(count).getString("order_id");
 String pickupaddress = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_data").getJSONObject(count).getString("pickup_address");
 String contact = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_data").getJSONObject(count).getString("contact");
 Log.d("HomeAcivity",": "+driverId+","+pickupaddress+","+contact);
singleton = new Singleton(driverId,pickupaddress,contact);
userDataParserArrayList.add(singleton);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Jobs jobs = new Jobs();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Order",userDataParserArrayList);
jobs.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

fragment1 oncreateview: to retrieve

```
userDataParserArrayList =  getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("Order");
```

ParcableClass() its not a singleton class only the name is singleton

```
public class Singleton implements Parcelable {

    private String orderId;
    private String pickupAddress;
    private String contact;


    Singleton(String orderId,String pickupAddress,String contact){

        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.pickupAddress = pickupAddress;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    protected Singleton(Parcel in) {
        orderId = in.readString();
        pickupAddress = in.readString();
        contact = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Singleton> CREATOR = new Creator<Singleton>() {
        @Override
        public Singleton createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Singleton(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Singleton[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Singleton[size];
        }
    };

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public String getPickupAddress() {
        return pickupAddress;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(orderId);
        dest.writeString(pickupAddress);
        dest.writeString(contact);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to pass an arraylist from an activity to fragments. You can access an arraylist of activity by getActivity.arraylist_name from your fragment.

Comment: "i am not able to do it" -> Are you receiving an error of some kind?

Comment: @bhargav can you give me an example

Comment: @clownba0t i am getting null pointer error in my adapter public int getItemCount() {
        return userDataParsers.size();

    }

Answer (score 0):

@bipin  First you need to add your fragment into activity, like below code

```
Jobs jobs = new Jobs(); 
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add("JOB_FRAGEMENT", jobs).commit();
```

After create "**Job Fragment**" you can access arrayList from your activity like below code

```
((YourActivityName)getActivity()).yourArrayList(); in onViewCreated() method;
```

And then use this list !!!

Comment: how to add jobs object to fragmentTransaction ?